# Can we evaluate $\int_{0}^{t_o} \cos(x(t)) dt $ from $\int_{0}^{t_o} \sin(x(t)) dt$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can we evaluate $\int_{0}^{t_o} \cos(x(t)) dt $ from $\int_{0}^{t_o} \sin(x(t)) dt$  given that $x$ and $t$ are two variables? Actual dependence of $x$ on $t$ is complicated so that it is supposed to be unknown.

Also it is known that:

- $t=0, x(t) = \frac{\pi}{2}$
- $t=t_o, x(t) = 0$

Is it possible to evaluate?

### EDIT

The source of this problem is a pursuit curve question, from **Problems in General Physics** by **IE Irodov : [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/IrodovProblemsInGeneralPhysics)**

> Point $A$ moves uniformly with velocity $v$ so that the vector $v$ 
>   is continually "aimed" at point $B$ which in its turn moves recti- 
>   linearly and uniformly with velocity $u < v$. At the initial moment of 
>   time $v$ is perpendicular to $u$ and the points are separated by a distance $l$. How soon will the points converge?
>   - *Problem 13 in Mechanics, Problems in General Physics by IE Irodov*

So I supposed that the particles meet at time $t_o$. Also I let the angle made by line joining $A$ and $B$ with the horizontal line as $x(t)$ (angle $x$ is a function of time). SO if the particles are to meet, then:

1. Distance travelled by $A$ relative to $B$ is simply initial distance between $A$ and $B$, which is $l$.

$$vt_o =l+\int_0^{t_o}u\cos(x(t))dt$$

2. Distance travelled by both $A$ and $B$ in horizontal direction must be same if they meet. So using this we get

$$u{t_o}=\int_0^{t_o}v\cos(x(t))dt$$

So this solves our problem.

3. Distance travelled by $A$ in horizontal direction in time $t_o$ will simply be initial distance between $A$ and $B$, ie, $l$ :

$$\int_0^{t_o}v\sin(x(t))dt = l$$

We clearly see that **Point** $1$ and $2$ are sufficient to solve that problem. We take the value of the integral from Point 2 and substitute in Point 1.

**My question** was that, can we use **Point** $1$ and $3$ alone to find $t_o$, or what I originally posted:

> Can we evaluate $\int_{0}^{t_o} \cos(x(t)) dt $ from $\int_{0}^{t_o} \sin(x(t)) dt$  given that $x$ and $t$ are two variables?

Answer (score 3):

note that $$\sin \left( x \right) =\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$$
then we get
$$\int_{0}^t\sin(x)dt=\int_{0}^t\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)dx=1-\cos(t)$$

Comment: I also know this identity then what do we do?

Comment: :-/ Apparently the OP wants $\int\sin(\color{red}x)~\mathrm d\color{red}t$, but aside from that, this answer is fine.  Your answers have been improving in content in my opinion, and I hope that's a trend ;)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I meant $x(t)$ only, but wrote it as $x$. If you read the question it is said that $x$ was dependent on $t$. Please can you open this question?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to determine $\int_0^{t_0}{\cos(x(t))\,dt}$ from $\int_0^{t_0}{\sin(x(t))\,dt}$. To show this, set $t_0 = 1$, and for $0<a<b<1$, let
$$ x_{a,b}(t) = \left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4a}t & 0\le t<a \\ \frac{\pi}{4} & a\le t < b \\ \frac{\pi}{4(1-b)} - \frac{\pi}{4(1-b)}t & b\le t\le 1\end{matrix}\right.. $$
In other words, $x_{a,b}$ is decreasing linearly from $\pi/2$ to $\pi/4$ on $[0,a]$, has constant value $\pi/4$ on $[a,b]$, and is decreasing from $\pi/4$ to $0$ on $[b,1]$. Notice that
\begin{align} \int_0^1{\cos(x_{a,b}(t))\,dt} &= \int_0^a{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4a}t\right)\,dt} + \int_a^b{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,dt} + \int_b^1{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4(1-b)} - \frac{\pi}{4(1-b)}t\right)\,dt} \\
&=\frac{4a}{\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\cos u\,du} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(b-a) + \frac{4(1-b)}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\cos u\,du} \\
&=\frac{4a}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(b-a) + \frac{4(1-b)}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)b
\end{align}
while by similar calculations we have
\begin{align} \int_0^1{\sin(x_{a,b}(t))\,dt} &= \frac{4a}{\pi}\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(b-a) + \frac{4(1-b)}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)a - \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b.
\end{align}
Thus, if we can find $0<a_1<b_1<1$ and $0<a_2<b_2<1$ such that
\begin{align} &\frac{4}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)a_1 - \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b_1\\
& = \frac{4}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)a_2 - \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b_2
\end{align}
but
\begin{align} &\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a_1 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)b_1 \\
&\ne \frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a_2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)b_2
\end{align}
then we have found $x_{a_1,b_1}\ne x_{a_2,b_2}$ such that $\int_0^1{\sin(x_{a_1,b_1}(t))\,dt} = \int_0^1{\sin(x_{a_2,b_2}(t))\,dt}$, but $\int_0^1{\cos(x_{a_1,b_1}(t))\,dt}\ne\int_0^1{\cos(x_{a_2,b_2}(t))\,dt}$.

Of course, finding such $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ is possible, since the lines of the form
$$- \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)a - \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b = \text{constant} $$
and lines of the form
$$  \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)b = \text{constant} $$
have different slopes, and hence choosing any line of the form $- \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)a - \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b = \text{constant}$ which intersects $\{0<a<b<1\}$ at infinitely many points gives infinitely many points where $- \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)a - \left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b$ is constant, but $\left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)b$ can take infinitely many different values.

---

One might object that the counterexample presented here is not smooth. This is not really an obstacle though. Suppose we have found the $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ above such that $\int_0^1{\sin(x_{a_1,b_1}(t))\,dt} = \int_0^1{\sin(x_{a_2,b_2}(t))\,dt}$, but $\int_0^1{\cos(x_{a_1,b_1}(t))\,dt}\ne\int_0^1{\cos(x_{a_2,b_2}(t))\,dt}$. We may perturb $x_{a_1,b_1}$ and $x_{a_2,b_2}$ to get $\tilde{x_1}\approx x_{a_1,b_1}$ and $\tilde{x_2}\approx x_{a_2,b_2}$ which are smooth, and since $\int_0^1{\sin(x_{a_1,b_1}(t))\,dt} = \int_0^1{\sin(x_{a_2,b_2}(t))\,dt}$, we can even choose the approximations to satisfy $\int_0^1{\sin(\tilde{x_1}(t))\,dt} = \int_0^1{\sin(\tilde{x_2}(t))\,dt}$. However, since
\begin{align} \left|\int_0^1{\cos(\tilde{x_1}(t)) - \cos(x_{a_1,b_1}(t))\,dt}\right|&\le\int_0^1{|\cos(\tilde{x_1}(t)) - \cos(x_{a_1,b_1}(t))|\,dt}\\
&\le\int_0^1{|\tilde{x_1}(t)-x_{a_1,b_1}(t)|\,dt}
\end{align}
and similarly for $\tilde{x_2}$ and $x_{a_2,b_2}$, by choosing the perturbations small enough, we can ensure that we still do not have $\int_0^1{\cos(\tilde{x_1}(t))\,dt} = \int_0^1{\cos(\tilde{x_2}(t))\,dt}$.

Comment: The answer given is $$t = \dfrac{vl}{v^2 - u^2}$$.

Comment: @123 what is the relevance of your comment?

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand your answer but didn't you say that it is not possible that $A$ and $B$ will meet ?

Comment: @123 I have edited the first sentence. I claim that knowing the value of $\int_0^{t_0}{\sin(x(t))\,dt}$ does not tell you the value of $\int_0^{t_0}{\cos(x(t))\,dt}$. I did not claim that $A$ and $B$ cannot meet. The answer is purely mathematical and has nothing to do with the physics problem attached to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem highly implausible. A function $x(t)$ that satisfies the properties you mentioned is
$$x(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(t)$$
with $t_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Wolfram Alpha gives us that 
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(t)\right)dt=\frac{\pi}{2}H_0\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
where $H_0$ is the Struve function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function, while 
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(t)\right)dt=\pi J_0\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html.

Although you can see that $H_0$ and $J_0$ are both solutions to that differential equation, they are quite different on the right hand side; one is $0$ and one is some gargantuan mess I will not write out. I think that because of this, it is highly implausible that you can do this; although there may be some deep underlying mathematics that I do not understand. Perhaps post your question on the physics site for help with it; I do not know physics so I can't help. ¯_(ツ)_/¯